# RoR+ in rjs add value from prompt to table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in js.rjs file i am shwoing prompt with textbox like

**page << "var name = prompt('Enter name:'); "**

i want to add the **value name** to the **table names**

is it possible to do from rjs

if so please guide me how to do it..

Comment: Do you want to save the value in the database table `names`, or insert it into an HTML `<table>` containing a list of names?

Comment: i want to save the value in database table names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't do this back and forwarding with rjs. You're returning javascript to be executed by the client, and you can't get the value back directly unless you embed another AJAX call into the javascript your return.

A better way to do this would be to use a single AJAX call. Use a `remote_form_for` with a `text_field` for the user to enter their `name` into, then POST it to your controller action and store it in the database in the normal fashion.

Something like:

```
# In your view
<% remote_form_for :user, :url => { :controller => :users, :action => :create } do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

# In your controller
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  @user.save
  render :update do |page|
    # Return whatever javascript you want here
    page << "alert('Created user')"
  end
end
```